# Drawing set of vectors using Metal

Tags: ios, metal

I need, using `Metal`, to create 3D model, which consist of thousands of vectors (lines). I know how to create model with triangles. But, can I do it by primitives, or only by triangles? Please, explaine or show example or class of Metal which I need to use for this task.

Comment: Metal has a `line` primitive that allows you to draw lines by specifying pairs of endpoints. The caveat is that lines are always one pixel wide (i.e., there is no control over line width). Can you describe the effect you're trying to achieve more precisely?

Comment: Thank you, just today found `.line` and `.lineStrip` in `MTLPrimitiveType` and using it in `drawPrimitives:`. If you'll create an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Metal has a `line` primitive that allows you to draw lines by specifying pairs of endpoints. You can specify that you want to draw lines with the first parameter (`type`) of any draw call. The caveat is that lines are always one pixel wide (i.e., there is no control over line width).